# SQL connection in .NET Core slow

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, .net-8.0

I am working on an API project that uses the latest .NET 8 which connects to a remote database using EF Core. The initial connection to the database takes 21 seconds approximately. The same method also connects to 2 other databases and they are very quick ~200ms.

**What troubleshooting have I done?**

- I connected to that database from the same dev machine using SSMS and it connects within milliseconds.
- I changed my connection to the database from using EF Core to ADO.NET, and still the same.
- I created a brand-new console app and tried connecting to the database and its still take 21 seconds.
- Then I created a .NET Framework console app and tested, it connects within milliseconds.

I did a bit of googling and I learned that the way .NET Core and .NET Framework handle connection strings is different. And when I remove the port number from the connection string it is super quick.

**Update 1** - I initially thought removing the default port from the connection string makes it quick. But after further testing its definitely not the case.

This is sample code that I did to test from console app.

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;

var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
Console.WriteLine("##############Starting database call.##################");

var connectionString = "Data Source=prod-***********,1433;Initial Catalog=vspp_3;User ID=**************;Password=************; TrustServerCertificate=True; Connect Timeout=30;";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM wb_old", connection))
    {
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully queried the database.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Query executed, but no data was returned.");
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine($"############################Completed database call in {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms #################");

Console.ReadLine();
```

I am interested to know why would it be slow in .NET Core and works great in .NET Framework?

Comment: Is the .NET 8 app using the legacy `System.Data.SqlClient` like the test client, or is it using the modern `Microsoft.Data.SqlCient`? Is it using an instance name in the `Server` connection string property? Could be experiencing communication issues with the SQL Browser service on the target server - udp/1434 needs to be open and accessible for SSRP (SQL Server Resolution Protocol) to work with instance names.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning : My original app is using `Microsoft.Data.SqlCient` and in the test app I tried with both `Microsoft.Data.SqlCient` and `System.Data.SqlClient`. No, I am not using an instance name, but using a domain name of the Db which is hosted in AWS

Comment: Start a wireshark trace and see where the delay is, it has quite good TDS filter. You can also compare how packets are being send between the different frameworks, Noone here is likely to help you since i have a feeling most people don't have 20 secs connection delays so it's likely something with your topology

Comment: @siggemannen : I understand its not a common issue and it's to do with some of the DB.  Because as I said it is happening even from a brand-new console project using ADO.net. The database is hosted by a third-party so I think they will need to install wireshark and check. But what is confusing is why is the older .Net 4.8 framework works all good?

Comment: You can run the trace on your local comp.

Comment: Your question is asking about the "initial connection time", but your code explicitly includes stopwatch output based on query completion. So, are you saying that your code sample outputs "...##Completed database call in 21000 ms##...", or that the single line of code `connection.Open()` is taking 21 seconds?

Comment: Its for opening the connection that it takes 21 seconds, query itself runs in milli-seconds